# R: Function() - How to check x y values with if else and sapply

Tags: r, function, if-statement

This is just an example of what I wanna do.. i'm trying to check if "Numbers2" is greater than "Numbers" .. with the code below.. am i doing it wrongly? it's a small problem but i'm new to R.. Im not getting the output I want and I cannot find the problem.
[image: output with current code]

```
df = data.frame(YesNo = c("yes","no","yes","no"), 
            Numbers = c(4, 5, 10, 10),
            Numbers2 = c(5,1,11,11))
df

rownames(df) = c("Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4")
df


improvement1 = function(x,y) {
  if(x >= y){
    return("Improve")
  } else {
    return("No")
  }
}

df$Improvement=sapply(df$Numbers, df$Numbers2, FUN=improvement1)
View(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `>` comparator is vectorized, you dont need for loops at all.

```
df$Improvement<-c('NO', 'Improve')[1 + (df$Numbers > df$Numbers2)]

#Or just use ifelse as in @Ben Norris' answer:

df$Improvement=ifelse(Numbers>Numers2, 'Improvement', 'No')
```

If you really want to use a loop function, you should be using `mapply()`, as in:

```
df$Improvement=mapply(FUN=improvement1, df$Numbers, df$Numbers2)
```

`mapply` loops through several vector imputs elementwise.
When we call `mapply(my_function, x, y)`, the output is `c(my_function(x[[1]], y[[1]]), my_function(x[[2]], y[[2]]), .....)` which seems to be what you want

Answer (score 1):

This issue is with `if`, which expects a single logical value. However, you are comparing two vectors. We get this warning on your code:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x >= y) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Since only the first element is being used, you get unexpected results. You need a vectorized solution, which is `ifelse()`.

```
improvement1 = function(x,y) {
  ifelse(x >= y, "Improve", "No")
}

df$Improvement = improvement1(df$Numbers, df$Numbers2)
df
      YesNo Numbers Numbers2 Improvement
Test1   yes       4        5          No
Test2    no       5        1     Improve
Test3   yes      10       11          No
Test4    no      10       11          No
```

Comment: Also note that `sapply()` is a problem here. Since you are feeding in two vectors, `sapply()` will return a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: even with ifelse, it still shows the wrong output right? in your code above.. its not showing the correct output for Test1 and Test2